# Convert XORShift algorithm from C code to Delphi Code

Tags: c, delphi

I have code in C, and I want to convert it to Delphi. What I have done is it right or wrong?

```
uint64_t s[ 16 ];
int p;

uint64_t next(void) {
  uint64_t s0 = s[ p ];
  uint64_t s1 = s[ p = ( p + 1 ) & 15 ];
  s1 ^= s1 << 31; // a
  s1 ^= s1 >> 11; // b
  s0 ^= s0 >> 30; // c
  return ( s[ p ] = s0 ^ s1 ) * 1181783497276652981LL;
```

Delphi Code:

```
Function next() : UInt64;
var 
  s : array of UInt64;
  s0, s1 : UInt64;
  p : integer;
begin 
  SetLength(s, 16);
  s0 := s[p];
  p := ( p + 1 ) and 15;
  s1 := s[p];
  s1 := s1 xor (s1 shl 31);
  s1 := s1 xor (s1 shr 11);
  s0 := s0 xor (s0 shr 30);
  s[p] := (s0 xor s1) * 1181783497276652981;
  result := s[p]; 
end;
```

Comment: Lets start with a simple question: Does it compile? A more complicated question: If it compiles, does it give you the expected result?

Comment: "p" defined as local variable and will be undefined. If you try to compile it, compiler will show warning. You never tried to compile it? Try to run some tests on both implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your translation is wrong in a number of ways. Beyond that your Delphi code does not compile, and indeed nor does the C code.

The end of the function should be:

```
s[p] := s0 xor s1;
Result := s[p] * 1181783497276652981;
```

It is wasteful to use a heap allocated array here. Use a fixed length array instead.

The other problem that I can see is that `s` and `p` have wider scope in the C code than the Delphi code. We can't see how they are initialized in the C code because unfortunately you removed much of the code that matters. Clearly though, your Delphi code cannot work with that difference. In the C code `s` is meant to persist between different invocations. Likewise `p`.

Perhaps the code should be:

```
var 
  s: array [0..15] of UInt64;
  p: Integer;

function next() : UInt64;
var
  s0, s1 : UInt64;
begin 
  s0 := s[p];
  p := ( p + 1 ) and 15;
  s1 := s[p];
  s1 := s1 xor (s1 shl 31);
  s1 := s1 xor (s1 shr 11);
  s0 := s0 xor (s0 shr 30);
  s[p] := s0 xor s1;
  Result := s[p] * 1181783497276652981;
end;
```

But again, we don't know how `s` and `p` are meant to be initialised. Do you?

What you need to do is some testing. Compare the output from both programs. If they agree, great. If they don't, debug the Delphi program to find out where it diverges.

Comment: C code is not mine I have taken from this paper "An experimental exploration of Marsaglia's xorshift generators, scrambled"

Comment: I don't think that changes anything.

Comment: I have made these changes:

- p, s Public variables; p := 0; // initial value.
- s filled by another function.

Comment: How are you getting on testing?

Comment: Delphi code is working now, but I do not have a result of C code. I need to get a result of C then compares it with the result of Delphi. 
Do you have any suggestions ??

Comment: I suggest you do some debugging. Output intermediate values to determine where the code diverges.

Comment: The paper says: "The array s should be initialized to a nonzero seed before calling next()". And in the original code, both `s` and `p` are global variables, i.e. outside the routine `next()`. Your translation is correct.

Comment: @SHdotCom: Since this is a random number generator, it is expected that you get a different result, unless you perform the exact same initialization. This means that both the C and the Delphi code should initialize the array s with the same values. If neither does any initialization, then you will of course get different results.

Comment: @SHdotCom: FWIW, p should also be initialized the same way, of course (probably to 0), before next() is called the first time.